# How to use partial views using the Erubis gem

Tags: partial-views, partial, eruby, erubis

I am not using Ruby on Rails, this is a stand alone app using the the erubis gem. I have a few template files which I use for generating a static website, and would like to separate the header, body, and footer sections in the files.

For example

```
<%= render "header.eruby" %>

<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-2 columns" id="Add_Space"></div>

  <div class="large-10 columns">
    <div class="row">

    <% for project in projects %>
      <div class="row proj_bar">
        <div class="large-12 columns" style="background-image: url('<%= project.preview.image %>')" >
          <div class="project_description" >
            <% for paragraph in project.preview.description.paragraphs %>
              <p><%= paragraph %></p>
            <% end %> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.3.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

How can I implement something akin to the first line like the following?

```
<%= render "header.eruby" %>
```